# Points where no lines intersect both sides of an angle in the Poincaré's disk model.

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm suppose to: Draw an angle and mark the region of points P for which the following holds: there is no line that intersects the sides of the angle and goes through P

I can't see how this is possible since I believed that you could draw a line through any two points (obviously wrong, but how?). I've looked through my book college geometry and can't find any explanation for this.

In the picture is the solution after talking to my professor, the marked areas are where the points exists that only intersect one of the sides of the angle ABE:
[Picture of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAbqR.png)

Comment: You should probably read that condition as "There is no line that intersects **BOTH** sides of the angle and goes through $P$." (You're correct that there will always be lines that go through a given point and **one** side of the angle. "Two points determine a line" is an axiom that spans Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry.)

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot. I think the solution must be all points on the interior of the sides from the angle. Atleast I'm sure that all exterior points can be excluded.

If I could give you correct answer or some points or something I would but I don't know the site well enough.

Comment: Hmm, I actually think that if you have an angle, it must be inside the circle and not on the edge (since all lines cut the sides of the circle by a 90 degree angle, they form a 0 degree angle with eachother). But then the points are not only the ones on the interior of the angle, but also if you extend the sides of the angle through the angle to behind it those points should fulfill the requirements as well. In other words extend the sides of the angle as line segments and all points between the lines will only cut 1 side segment at most.

Comment: Not sure : why can you exclude all external points ?

Comment: Willemien Ignore my previous comments I didn't figure out the solution until my professor showed me. I've included a link to a picture in my original post which marks the areas where all points does not intersect either side of the angle.

Answer (score 0):

I've included an image of the solution in my original post. if there is some angle ABE, where the ray AB intersects the poincare disk in C, and ray BE intersects the poincare disk in G. Then draw a line from C to G. All the points between that line and the Poincare disk's outer circle won't intersect both rays BA and BE.

also extend the ray to a line so that line BA intersects the poincare disk in D and line BE intersects the poincare disk in F (behind the angle). Then the points between BF, BD and the Poincare disk's outer circle segment won't intersect both rays BE and BA.

Image of solution is in my original post.